# sql oracle duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle, join, self

Here's my ORACLE table

```
HAVE******
asset_no, sub,          add_dtm
11510     FOX HOLLOW    8/1/2008 8:00:01 AM
11510     FOX HOLLOW    11/1/2011 1:30:01 PM
11510     FOX HOLLOW    10/1/2012 8:00:01 AM
11511     TOWNE NORTH   6/25/2008 5:23:15 PM
11512     EAST SUB      7/23/2010 2:50:44 PM

WANT******
11510     FOX HOLLOW    10/1/2012 8:00:01 AM
11511     TOWNE NORTH   6/25/2008 5:23:15 PM
11512     EAST SUB      7/23/2010 2:50:44 PM
```

i have duplicate asset_no in the table as above (11510) with different dates i need the max date for each duplicate asset_no.  When i do a select asset_no, max(add_dtm) i get what i want but i need the 'sub' field too, select asset_no, sub, max(add_dtm), then thats when i get the result shown above.

Comment: I need the entire record that has the most greatest date in add_dtm field for 11510

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do this - see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/98439/6) of all queries

You can use a subquery:

```
select t1.asset_no,
  t1.sub,
  t1.add_dtm
from table1 t1
inner join
(
  select max(add_dtm) mxdate, asset_no
  from table1
  group by asset_no
) t2
  on t1.add_dtm = t2.mxdate
  and t1.asset_no = t2.asset_no
```

or you can use `CTE` using `row_number()`:

```
with cte as
(
  select asset_no,
    sub,
    add_dtm,
    row_number() over(partition by asset_no 
                      order by add_dtm desc) rn
  from table1
) 
select *
from cte
where rn = 1
```

Or without CTE using `row_number()`:

```
select *
from 
(
  select asset_no,
    sub,
    add_dtm,
    row_number() over(partition by asset_no 
                      order by add_dtm desc) rn
  from table1
) x
where rn = 1
```

Comment: @Fonzy yes, all three will work in Oracle.  see my demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/98439/6

Answer (score 2):

Probably the simplest way is to use an analytic (aka. window) function, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        YOUR_TABLE.*, 
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY asset_no ORDER BY add_dtm DESC) R
    FROM YOUR_TABLE
)
WHERE R = 1
```

Note that this will return multiple rows in case you have multiple equal maximal dates (for the same `asset_no`). To pick just one of them (at random), you could use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER ...`.

---

Or, do it the old-fashion way:

```
SELECT *
FROM YOUR_TABLE T1
WHERE
    add_dtm = (
        SELECT MAX(add_dtm)
        FROM YOUR_TABLE T2
        WHERE T1.asset_no = T2.asset_no
    );
```

This would work even on a DBMS that doesn't support analytic functions (unlike Oracle).

[[SQL Fiddle]](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4549e/6)

Comment: IMHO the second form is more intuitive and readable, so I'm curious: is there a performance advantage for the first form over the second?

Comment: @DReispt It's hard to tell on the small amount of data and the incomplete (PK-less and index-less) table. The execution plans look different (expand the "View Execution Plan" in SQL Fiddle), but that can often happen on a small amount of data - it is possible they will "converge" as the data grows. The only reliable way to know is to **measure** on realistic amounts of data.

Comment: Just did a test on a table with ~500k records. Both queries count ~20k results. The `RANK() OVER` takes >1.5 secs; the `SELECT MAX` method takes <0.5 secs.

Comment: @DReispt - did you exclude the effect of caching, e.g. running each several times and in reverse order? Not saying your result is wrong, it depends on the data and indexes etc., but a comparison of a single run isn't necessarily definitive.

Comment: Yes, I ran each SQL several times and alternated between them more than once. And yes, anyone reading this, try your own tests, since these result can be very specific to my table, indexes and data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT asset_no, sub,add_dtm, 
row_number() over (partition by asset_no, sub order by add_dttm desc) 
rn from table1
)

select * from cte where rn = 1;
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention it's oracle

Comment: Not sure using `rownum` as a column alias is a good idea (if it works at all); at best it's ambiguous. (The blank line will also upset SQL*Plus and maybe other clients).